TCPDF "unable to read file: helvetica.json"
i installed the newest TCPDF version from the https://github.com/tecnickcom/tc-lib-pdf repo.
and when i try this in my code

  #[Route('/pdf/{id}', name: 'app_test_pdf')]
    public function pdf(Request $request, Project $project): Response
    {
        $pdf = new Tcpdf();

        $pdf->setPDFFilename('project.pdf');
        $pdf->setTitle('Project');
        $pdf->setCreator('me');// Set default header and footer
        $pdf->setKeywords('TCPDF tc-lib-pdf example');
        $pdf->setPDFFilename('test_index.pdf');
        $pdf->setViewerPreferences(['DisplayDocTitle' => true]);
        $pdf->enableDefaultPageContent();
        $bfont1 = $pdf->font->insert($pdf->pon, 'helvetica', '', 12);

        $page01 = $pdf->addPage();

        $rawpdf = $pdf->getOutPDFString();

        $pdf->renderPDF($rawpdf);
        // Close and output PDF to string (no file on the filesystem)
        $pdf->savePDF("uploads",$pdf->getOutPDFString());
    }

I get the error Uncaught PHP Exception Com\Tecnick\Pdf\Font\Exception: "unable to read file: helvetica.json" at Stack.php line 198
but in my vendor folder i see tecnickcom as in the [screenshot shown](https://i.sstatic.net/vCurxRo7.png) and i tried in the tc-lib-pdf folder to do the command.
make deps fonts

Does anyone has an idea to my issue?
